# How to show default tab in android?

Tags: android

I have an activity which add tablayout namely "A","B" when I move to "B" and exit that activity and again resumed to that activity Tab "B" is visible to me.but I want whenever return to that activity always show tab "A". how can I do that

code:-

```
    public void init() {
    s_oCloginSession = new CLoginSessionManagement(CMainActivity.this);// object creation of Login Session...
    setupToolbar();// setting toolbar

    // navigation bar code
    m_Drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);//finding id of drawerlayout
    s_drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, m_Drawer, m_Toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    m_Drawer.setDrawerListener(s_drawerToggle);
    m_Drawer.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
    s_drawerToggle.syncState();

    NavigationView m_Navigation = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    m_Navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    m_TabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);// finding Id of tablayout
    m_ViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);//finding Id of ViewPager
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Deals"));// add deal listin tab
    m_TabLayout.addTab(m_TabLayout.newTab().setText("Stories"));// add stories tab
    m_TabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);// setting Gravity of Tab


    CDealMainListingPager m_oDealMainScreenPager = new CDealMainListingPager(getSupportFragmentManager(), m_TabLayout.getTabCount());
    m_ViewPager.setAdapter(m_oDealMainScreenPager);// adiing adapter to ViewPager
    m_ViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(m_TabLayout));// performing action of page changing
    m_TabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            m_ViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: You don't need two diff. activities for tabs, Tab View will be added in your main activity and inside that activity, each tab will have respective fragment. Please check this tutorial - http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/

Comment: you can use a var for it and then change position.

Comment: I have a MainActivity in which I added Tabview inside activity but I want whenever resumed to MainActivity always want to show Tab"A"

Comment: where are you setting Current item in pager ?

Comment: The code I posted is all about that

Comment: Oh no. What are you doing man?

Comment: `myTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);` do something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend  `m_ViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);` will help you in `onResume` method like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if(m_ViewPager!=null){
        m_ViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    }
}
```